# Reduce to Object error: cannot create property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to create an object with a function inputs of an array and a callback.

It's not working as intended

```js
function arrToObj(array, callback) {

  return array.reduce((acc, currStr) => {
    return acc[currStr] = callback(currStr)
  }, {})
}
const arrOfStrings = ['str1', 'str2'];
const capitalize = str => str.toUpperCase();
console.log(arrToObj(arrOfStrings, capitalize)); // expecting: {str1 : STR1, str2 : STR2}
```

I'm getting an error: Type Error on line 4: Cannot create property 'str2' on string 'STR1'

I feel like there is something I've missed fundamentally with reduce.
I appreciate any insights to further my knowledge.

Comment: Looks like you want to return the entire `acc` object, not the value of the property you just assigned

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your `reduce` function. You are not returning the `acc` at the end.

```js
function arrToObj(array, callback) {
  return array.reduce((acc, currStr) => {
    acc[currStr] = callback(currStr);
    return acc;
  }, {})
}

const arrOfStrings = ['str1', 'str2'];
const capitalize = str => str.toUpperCase();
console.log(arrToObj(arrOfStrings, capitalize)); // expecting: {str1 : STR1, str2 : STR2}
```

Comment: I appreciate the insight very much! 

There was def some misunderstanding in reduce.  Thank you for teaching me something!

Comment: @SabreTheCat Happy to help. If this resolved your question please mark this as the answer.